# Closed form solution of this Vandermonde-like Identity

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, permutations

Can a closed form solution for the following expression be obtained? ($\alpha, n, m$ are constants)
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k\alpha^i \binom{n}{i}\binom{m}{k-i}
$$

I know that $\binom{n+m}{k} = \sum_{i=0}^k\binom{n}{i}\binom{m}{k-i}$ is Vandermonde's identity

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $$\binom{m}{k} \, _2F_1(-k,-n;-k+m+1;\alpha )$$ where $F$ is the hypergeometric function.

Comment: $\alpha^i{n\choose i}=[x^i](1+\alpha \cdot x)^n$ and ${m\choose k-i}=[x^{k-i}](1+x)^{m}$, then 

$\sum_{i=0}^k\alpha^i \binom{n}{i}\binom{m}{k-i}$ is the coeff of $x^k$ in the expansion of $(1+\alpha \cdot x)^n(1+x)^{m}. $